# Available modules in node script

Tags: javascript, node.js

why do I get different results when trying to find out more about the http module in node.js in the following to ways?

1. If I enter the node REPL and then print the content of the http module, i.e. if I run

   ```
   me@mymachine:~> node
   > console.log(http)
   ```

   I get all the details of the http object:

   ```
   { IncomingMessage: 
       { [Function: IncomingMessage]
           super_:
             {
   ...
   ```
2. If I write a script file called, say, **script.js** containing the following single line

   ```
   console.log(http);
   ```

   and execute it by running

   ```
   node script.js
   ```

   I get

   ```
   ReferenceError: http is not defined
   ```

I would have expected both cases to behave in the same way - either the http module is preloaded or not. Why is there a difference? What am I getting wrong here?

I thought I could 'fix' this by preloading module http by running (in version 2)

```
node -r http script.js
```

Shouldn't this preload module http and thus avoid the reference error?

Looking forward to your input!

Comment: The Node REPL is not just plain Node; it's a specific set of tools, and what you're observing is one of its features.

Answer (score 2):

Repl has all the standard Node.js core modules required by default.

https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_accessing_core_node_js_modules

Comment: Thanks - that explains it. Still, I am wondering why I can't preload the module using the `-r` parameter?

Comment: That's indeed interesting. I am not sure but I am suspecting that the `-r` parameter doesn't evaluate the `global.fs = require('fs')` as the REPL does. Someone else could shed some light here.